# Neural Network Simple Time Series Prediction giving Wrong Results in R

Tags: r, neural-network

This should give as 61 as output as I am using simple example of training number from 1 to 59 as input and having 60 minute as output...I have then using 2 to 60 numbers and seeing the result its giving as 60 which is way wrong as its simple series?

```
library("neuralnet")
testtime=59
i=59
s=61
testinput=0
testresults_values=0
testtrainingoutput=0

xnam_2 <- paste0("testinput[",1:i,"]")
(fmla_2 <- as.formula(paste("testInsertoutput[",60,"]~", paste(xnam_2, collapse= "+"))))



   testtraininginput=seq(1,59,by=1)

   testinput[1:59]=testtraininginput

   testtrainingoutput[60] <- 60

    #if(is.na(trainingoutput)==TRUE){break} - Can be used for future

    testInsertoutput=testtrainingoutput

    data=cbind(testinput,testInsertoutput)

    testnet.sqrt<- neuralnet(fmla_2,data,hidden=1)

    testdata_new<- seq(2,60,by=1)
    testnewvale=as.data.frame(t(testdata_new))

    testnet.results <- compute(testnet.sqrt,testnewvale[,1:testtime]) #Run them through the neural 
    testresults_values=testnet.results$net.result

testresults_values
```

Comment: Do you have other documentation to suggest that your "trained" net will always increment?

Comment: You have a single observation and 60 variables: unsurprisingly, the neural network gives an (almost) constant model.

Comment: @VincentZoonekynd thanks for verifying my naive intuition as to the source of the problem.  :-)

Comment: Thanks Vincent ZooneKynd and Carl Withhoft for your answer...so how should I setup the problem i.e. taking numbers and training for one output i.e. number from 1 to 5 and having 6 as output...and then giving number from 2 to 6..and in that case output should be 7...

Comment: I know nothing about neural nets & training, and it appears you're not far ahead of me :-( , so I recommend talking w/ someone who is knowledgeable to understand what it means to "train" a net to learn to count.